# How does MongoDB node.js find API call know if you are passing fields or options as an argument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

MongoDB node.js [find API call](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) allows both `selector, fields, callback?` and `selector, options, callback?`. How does it differ between fields and options object? They can both be objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/collection/query.js).

The algorithm is quite simple: iterate over each provided value and check if it is a known option. If it's not an option, it must be a field.

```
var testForFields = {
    limit: 1, sort: 1, fields:1, skip: 1, hint: 1, explain: 1, snapshot: 1, timeout: 1, tailable: 1, tailableRetryInterval: 1
  , numberOfRetries: 1, awaitdata: 1, exhaust: 1, batchSize: 1, returnKey: 1, maxScan: 1, min: 1, max: 1, showDiskLoc: 1
  , comment: 1, raw: 1, readPreference: 1, partial: 1, read: 1, dbName: 1, oplogReplay: 1, connection: 1
};
```

Further down, in the `find` method:

```
if(len === 2 && !Array.isArray(fields)) {
    var fieldKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fields);
    var is_option = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < fieldKeys.length; i++) {
      if(testForFields[fieldKeys[i]] != null) {
        is_option = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(is_option) {
      options = fields;
      fields = undefined;
    } else {
      options = {};
    }
  }
```

Comment: I somehow missed `testForFields`. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Hm, if my field is named the same as any of options, it will take the object as options? This is quite fragile, no?